# How to pair a UNION SQL with a third table

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I have the following query

```
SELECT Distinct Client_ID, add_column_name(s) FROM table1
UNION
SELECT Distinct Client_ID, add_column_name(s) FROM table2
```

and I have a third Table which I want to bring additional data from to add to these tables 1 and 2 such as

```
SELECT Distinct Product_ID FROM table3
```

and join it on Client_ID (which exists in tables 1, 2, and 3), how would I do that? Tables 1 and 2 do not have the Product_ID, but I only want the Client_IDs which exist in tables 1 and 2 to have the Product_ID added to them as table 3 and only Product_ID as table 3 has other columns as well that i don't want and also Table 3 may have additional Client_IDs which don't exist in tables 1 and 2.

Comment: Please show some sample data and expected results.

Comment: `UNION` is somewhat rare in queries, especially on different tables (`UNION ALL` is a little less rare, but still rare). `DISTINCT` is also rare. So you are doing two rare things here in one query. While this is easily done (as you can select from subqueries), I wonder whether your data model may be flawed to make this necessary. Maybe you want to tell us about the three tables involved here.

Comment: Since you have multiple answers, none of which are accepted, I think should post sample data from each of those table and also post sample output so it's clear what exactly you're looking for. If you can throw some DDL statements in there, that would be magical

Comment: Why you gotta vote me down like that Isildur? smh...

Comment: @Mo-L I did not. I almost always rather comment than downvote

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would use `JOIN`:

```
SELECT t12.*, t3.product_id
FROM (SELECT Client_ID, add_column_name(s) FROM table1
      UNION
      SELECT Client_ID, add_column_name(s) FROM table2
     ) t12 LEFT JOIN
     table3 t3
     ON t12.Client_ID = t3.Client_ID;
```

Note that `SELECT DISTINCT` is redundant with `UNION`, because `UNION` removes duplicates.

Comment: To also celebrate your 1000K. @GondonLinoff!

Comment: +1. I actually after a while wanted to see if the 1000k milestone is reached. Seems I catched the right moment :)

Comment: I only want to pull the product_IDs from Table 3, matched to Table 1 and 2s Client_IDs, not pull everything from table 3

Comment: @Mo-L . . . This only includes matching rows from table 3.

Comment: @Mo-L Instead of t3.*, just do t3.product_id

Answer (score 0):

You can use the query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT Distinct Client_ID, name FROM table1
    UNION
    SELECT Distinct Client_ID, name FROM table2
) A,
table3 B
WHERE A.CLIENT_ID=B.CLIENT_ID;
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT Distinct Client_ID, name FROM table1
    UNION
    SELECT Distinct Client_ID, name FROM table2
) A JOIN
table3 B
ON A.CLIENT_ID=B.CLIENT_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is, you want extra information from Table3 for the Client_IDs present in Table1 & Table2.

```sql
SELECT Client_ID, Product_ID FROM Table3 -- you have mentioned that product_id is only in Table3
WHERE client_ID IN
(
SELECT Client_ID FROM Table1
UNION 
SELECT Client_ID FROM Table2
)
```

Comment: I am getting this error which is literally the line of my last Parenthesis

Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 165
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.